# SQL Server Management Studio (V17.7) function tooltip not shown

Tags: sql-server

I am running SQL Server Management Studio (17.7). The issue is that as I type function names say "AVG(" no tool tip appears that should show the all the parameters of the function.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Toggle Completion Mode` checked?

Comment: Yes Johny.. It is on...